# Constraint for classes defined inside a static class

Tags: c#, namespaces

Hello is there any way to constrain a generic method for classes which are defined inside a static class?

```
static class Container {
    class A {
    }
    class B {
    }
}

static class ContainerExtension
{
    //(where T  is a class defined in class Container)
    public int[] ToArray<T>(T array) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question, please. I assumed your issue was that you hadn't defined ToArray as `ToArray<T>(T array) where ....` and added an answer, but now I feel that your question is asking how to constrain it to _any_ of the _nested classes_ within `Container`. Which are you asking? If it's the latter, then no, you can't.

Comment: I want to constrain the T for classes that are nested inside Container.

Comment: @Adrian The only way you can do that is if all of the classes implement a common interface or inherit from the same base class, at which point it makes no difference that they are nested classes.

Comment: I've reformatted your code (please take care over formatting in future) and made the `ToArray` method generic, which is what I assume you meant. I've also removed the extra `()` at the end of your class declaration. (Using real code as far as possible is very helpful.)

Comment: Yes i didn't want to follow this approach thinking there's a more elegant way.

Comment: I recommend accepting Jon's answer. For one, he's correct, and for another, he's [Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to constrain a generic method for classes which are defined inside a static class?

No, there isn't.

The only type constraints are:

- Requiring a public parameterless constructor (`where T : new()`)
- Requiring it to be a reference type (`where T : class`)
- Requiring it to be a non-nullable value type (`where T : struct`)
- Requiring an identity conversion to a particular type or type parameter (`where T : Button` or whatever)

There no constraint for "contained within a particular type" nor would I expect that to be a new feature on the way - it sounds like a very niche use case.

You could create an interface that only those types implement, but that's about as close as I can suggest. (If it's a private interface declared in the same containing class, only those classes *could* implement it - but then the generic method would need to be private too.)